# DataTemplate in FlipView having 2 UserControls, one at a time

Tags: c#, user-controls, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, flipview

I'm building a picture viewing app. In landscape, it opens like an open book showing 2 consecutive images. In portrait, it shows an individual image.
I'm thinking of using a UserControl for each of these 2 ViewState inside the DataTemplate of my FlipView. And then change their Visibility in the Current_SizeChanged event.

Here's my Xaml with only one UserControl set to the DataTemplate:

```
<FlipView x:Name="flipView1" SelectionChanged="flipView1_SelectionChanged">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:portraitControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

But a DataTemplate can't contain more than one UserControl. Is there a way I can **bind a local UserControl** to my DataTemplate to assign to it my "portraitControl" or "landscapeControl" in the code not in Xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to create two data templates, each has a user control:

```
<DataTemplate x:key = "portraitTemplate">
            <local:portraitControl/>
 </DataTemplate>

 <DataTemplate x:key = "landscapeTemplate">
            <local:landscapeControl/>
 </DataTemplate>
```

in your Current_SizeChanged event switch between templates:

```
flipView1.ItemTemplate = Resources["portraitTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define 2 different templates in `XAML` and switch the item template in code.

```
  <DataTemplate x:key = "datatTemplate1" />

  <DataTemplate x:key = "datatTemplate2" />

  flipView1.ItemTemplate = Resources["datatTemplate1"] as DataTemplate
```